# Commutative local rings which satisfy Krull-Remak-Schmidt

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay-rings

> Question 1: Can the class of local (always noetherian and commutative) rings be classified for which the Krull-Remak-Schmidt theorem (KRS) holds for finitely generated modules? They contain for example all complete local rings.

> Question 2: Does every local Cohen-Macaulay ring for which KRS holds for finitely generated modules have a canonical module? This is true for complete local rings.

Comment: Your Question 2 is interesting. It is known that Henselian local rings have KRS, but I don't think it is yet known if Henselian local Cohen-Macaulay rings admit canonical module or not. M. Artin conjectured that excellent Henselian local rings have the complete approximation property; now V. Hinich, and later also C. Rotthaus, proved that local Cohen-Macaulay rings with (complete) approximation property admits canonical module; see Theorem (3.1) of https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-96-03244-3 and the discussion preceding it, and also see Theorem 4.1 of https://doi.org/10.1002/MANA.19931630124

Comment: ...(cont'd) now I don't know if there has been any recent developments in this direction after the two papers I mentioned above

Comment: KRS for fg modules holds in the semilocal complete setting (if $A$ is semilocal and noetherian and $\mathrm{rad}(A)$-adically complete, then any $A$-algebra $B$ that is fg as an $A$-module has KRS on its fg modules), as I'm sure you are aware. (If not, this is Th. 21.35 in T.Y. Lam, *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings*. Another reference, with interesting counterexamples, is A. Facchini, *Module Theory: Endomorphism rings and direct sum decompositions in some classes of modules*.) I'm not an expert, but I understand KRS won't go much further than this.